# Formatting duplicate column data in excel and matching additional data

Tags: excel, formatting, conditional-statements, match, vlookup

I am trying use excel formulas to manipulate and extract some data and a little stuck. I believe I need to use `Vlookup` but I'm a newbie.  I have been trying pretty hard with conditional formatting but only getting some of what I need.

**Scenario:**

My company acquired another company and I need to migrate users data stored on home drives.  I need to associate their existing `SamAccountName` with their new one along with the `UNC path` of their home drive.  I have all the info just not organized. Below you can see column A and B are new and old `SamAccountName`.  These rows match - new `SamAccountName` (`Column B`) = old `SamAccountName` (`Column A`).  There are about 1200 of these users (only listed a handful of dummy names).

`Column C` contains the full list of users home drive folders listed by `SamAccountName` along with their corresponding home drive `UNC path`.  There are about 2200 of these.  Names in `Column C` will also be in `Column B` and I can do a conditional format duplicate match easily.  What I need is the `new SamAccountName` from `Column A` to line up or link with the rest of the data.  For example you can see `flo567` in `Column A` = `eflossmore` (row 7) and `Column B`.  And you can see it is on the full list in row 9 `Column C` and `D`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9B6dz.jpg)

Ideally I need match duplicated on `Columns B` and `C`.  And since `Column D` is lined up with `C` I just need to figure out how to match the data in `A` and line it up with `D` -- maybe in `Column E`?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9yRp.jpg)

thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

In `Column E`, put the below formula on Row 1.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,C:D,2,FALSE)
```

Copy E1 and paste across the remaining cells below in `Column E`.